# Can't write out elements when useing xsl:if and count() together

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to write out all the artist elements if the total number of the artist elements is greater than x. I have the following xml:

```
<catalog>
<cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist scale="28">Bonnie Tyler</artist>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    <artist scale="30">Dolly Parton</artist>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Still got the blues</title>
    <artist scale="24">Gary Moore</artist>
</cd>
```

I have the following in xsl:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="/">
  <xsl:if test="count(catalog/cd/artist) &gt; 26">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post a complete (reproducible) example, not something taken out of its context. And show the expected output too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several errors in your XSLT code:

- using `titles` instead of `title` in the select-expression
- you were checking for counts greater than 26, but your sample XML has only three entries
- you were selecting the root node in `xsl:for-each`, but tried to access child nodes two levels down with `xsl:value-of`

This is a stylesheet that satisfies your requirments:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="/catalog">
  <xsl:if test="count(cd) > 2">
   <xsl:for-each select="cd">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
    </tr>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I tried several ways... I missed only the / before catalog. Could you please explain me why is it that necessary?

The > 26 was not an error, the original xml was bigger. This is the reason I wrote 'X' in the description.

Your answer is perfect! Thanks!

Comment: The ' /' char at the beginning selects the root element(The first and one and only, **a well-formed XML document can only have one root element**), so `/catalog` puts the "current node level/current node set" to everything contained between `<catalog>` and `</catalog>`.

Comment: Thanks! What if I have an cd element without artist? Originally I wanted to count artist....

Comment: Enclose the output of the relevant elements with `<xsl:if test="artists"> ... </xsl:if>`. If you just want to count artist-elements, you could use `<xsl:value-of select="count(//catalog/cd/artist)" />`. These expressions are spontaneously created, so if there's a problem, try to ask a new question how to globally count elements.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

For starters, this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/">
```

puts you in the context of the *root node*. From this context, the instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
```

returns nothing, because the current node has no `artist` child. And even it had, only the value of the first one would be returned (in XSLT 1.0). You need to use `xsl:for-each` or `xsl:apply-templates` to process the descendant nodes, if you want to write them out as individual table rows/cells.

As for:

```
<xsl:value-of select="titles"/>
```

there simply isn't such node in your input

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The titles is originally title. It's jus a typo.